# Copy five min before data into different folder in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am very new s3 please help me on this  I am trying to copy data between two folders but I need to copy 5 min before the current time. Please help

My input is below:

```
aws s3 ls s3://folder1/1/

2018-11-20 10:41:43 a.txt

2018-11-20 10:42:43 b.txt

2018-11-20 10:43:43 c.txt

2018-11-20 10:44:43 d.txt

2018-11-20 10:45:43 e.txt

2018-11-20 10:46:43 f.txt

2018-11-20 10:47:43 g.txt

2018-11-20 10:48:43 h.txt

2018-11-20 10:49:43 h.txt

2018-11-20 10:50:43 h.txt
```

Now I need to run the command that moves the data always 5 minutes before currentime

My output should be as below

```
aws s3 ls s3://folder2/1/

2018-11-20 10:41:43 a.txt

2018-11-20 10:42:43 b.txt

2018-11-20 10:43:43 c.txt

2018-11-20 10:44:43 d.txt

2018-11-20 10:45:43 e.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to write a script or a single command? Please, provide a bit more info or at least preferred language.

Comment: basically wanted to achieve with aws command, eventually I will integrate with my pyspark code. I wanted to be something like this "aws s3 mv <src> <dst> | {Timestamp-5 min)". THis command has to move all the files from src to destination before 5 min whatever , has been resided in the s3 src path to destination

Comment: Can you tell us more about your larger use-case? There might be a better way to achieve your goal, such as using `aws s3 sync`. Why do you only want to move files from the last 5 minutes? How often will this be executed? Will there be any files from _more_ than 5 minutes ago that you want to leave where they are? The more information you can provide, the better the chance of getting a useful answer. Feel free to edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for support . Use case is I have the json feed coming to s3 every sec. But I will be taking from s3 daily once at particular time. Now the problem is I when I run my process the data will be in streaminh mode to s3, so the plan is to collect all the json files which has arrived till 5 before . I use following statement to collect all the files from s3 .read_json=spark.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("s3a://a/").values())